TS2305: Module '"@fluidframework/synthesize"' has no exported member 'DependencyContainer'
Currently I am upgrading the Node JS version from 18.20.4 to 20.18.0 in my Angular application. While building the application I am facing the error as
"TS2305: Module '"@fluidframework/synthesize"' has no exported member 'DependencyContainer'"
The package "@fluidframework/synthesize" was configured as "^2.0.0-internal.4.1.2". Even upgraded to latest version 2.4, still the error is coming.
Please anyone let me know how to solve this issue.
Thanks.
